# How to scrape youtube videos to get more videos than on one page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube

I want to scrape youtube to collect descriptions about videos based on my search query. I am using BeautifulSoup4 to do so. I have successfully located the video URLs. 
The issue I am facing is that I want to collect at least 2000 video links per category. But on one request, YouTube only displays 20 videos. How do I collect the URLs of more videos?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://www.youtube.com"
BASE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

query = "travel+blogs"

r = requests.get(BASE_SEARCH_URL + query)
page = r.text
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
vids = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link '})

video_urls = [BASE_URL + vid['href'] for vid in vids]

print(video_urls)
```

The issue I am facing is that I want to collect at least 2000 video links per category. But on one request, YouTube only displays 20 videos. How do I collect the URLs of more videos?

Comment: You should analyze how to load more videos in requests, or do more request with some param in url. Use dev-tools to analyze youtube network requests

Comment: I was able to get to this part. But the issue that I now face is that after a certain number of requests, youtube  returns a captcha page instead of the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **Selenium** along with BeautifulSoup. 
Selenium allows you to scroll to the bottom of the page by importing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

and using `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.END)` to scroll to the bottom (`driver` is the Selenium Webdriver object)

For your use case, you can scroll to the bottom around 100 times in a loop, populating 20 results each time and you can use your scraping code above, after getting the raw HTML using `driver.page_source`

On a side note however I would suggest you to use the YouTube Data API. It's quite easy to get going with and is free. It would run much faster and more efficiently.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is more likely to use with javaScript Heavy websites but it is quite slow as compared to beautifulSoup when we are talking about only scraping the data.

So, I found a very simple way to deal with youtube infinite scrolling problem without using selenium.

following are the steps.

1.fetch URL
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PHP+tutorials

2.loop through below URL and Increment page by 1 every time. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PHP+tutorials&page=1

you will get 20 entries in each iteration.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
for i in range(1,10):
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php+tutorial"+"&page="+str(i)
    source = requests.get(url).text
    code = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    print(code.prettify())
```

you will get the code file for every page containing 20 videos each.

Comment: The page argument in the URL is no longer working, and each iteration, at least on Chrome (not a headless browser), shows the same results.